# No puedo enviar correo desde mi sitio web con html y php

Tags: php, html, email

tengo el siguente problema.
Tengo mi sitio web en tonohost, la pagina para enviar correo es: http://nutrivida.tonohost.com/WF_Contactenos.html, utilizo html y php, pero he probado muchas cosas pero no he podido enviar correo. Me comunique con tonohost, y me dicen que su servicio de enviar correo esta bien. He querido hacer pruebas con un codigo php sencillo, pero aun así no he podido, este es el código(enviar.php):

```
<?php
// El mensaje
$mensaje = "Línea 1\r\nLínea 2\r\nLínea 3";

// Si cualquier línea es más larga de 70 caracteres, se debería usar wordwrap()
$mensaje = wordwrap($mensaje, 70, "\r\n");

// Enviarlo
mail('micorreo@gmail.com', 'Mi título', $mensaje);
header('Location:WF_Contactenos.html');
?>
```

Yo lo llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post">
...
<div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                    <button id="btn_enviar" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: has probado entrando directamente en el archivo desde el cual envías el correo?

Comment: si, pero no funciona

Comment: y si utilizas PHPMailer para poder tener mas control de la configuración? o no es una opción para tu proyecto?.